# Safari, single-page app and "Swipe between pages" OS X option

Tags: javascript, safari, osx-lion

I have a single-page app with internal content being able to swipe (I use iScroll library). It is working nicely everywhere, except for a single case: OS X Safari with "Swipe between pages" option is turned on.

In OS X Safari, when I do a 2-finger gesture, the whole app pans left/right and reveals a page that was before/after the current app in navigation history.

Is there any way I can battle this behavior through client-side JavaScript?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see why that should be possible; it's essentially a shorthand for pressing the "previous page" button. And FWIW, you shouldn't be trying to change and/or block browser functionality.

Answer (score -1):

use prevent default inside the event handler.